# jquery ajax call in onsubmit function is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have form submission page add_sale.php and an ajax page ajx_check_sale.php.Ajax call is inthe onsubmit function.But ajax is not worikng.Anybody give any solution plz..

I have form submission page add_sale.php and an ajax page ajx_check_sale.php.Ajax call is inthe onsubmit function.But ajax is not worikng.Anybody give any solution plz..

add_sale.php

```
function validate_form() {
  var cust_name = $('#cust_name').val();
  var total = $('#total').val();
  var sale_type = $('#sale_type').val();

  if (sale_type == 'return') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'ajx_check_sale.php',
      data: 'cust_name=' + cust_name + '&total=' + total,
      success: function(msg) {

        alert(msg);
        /*if(msg==0)
               {

                 alert("Return is greater then sale"); 
                 return false;  
               } */
      }
    });
  }
}

<form action="" method="post" name="adFrm" onSubmit="return validate_form()">
    <select name="sale_type" style="width:130px;" 
    id="sale_type"   onchange="sale_credit(this.value)"  >

        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option   value="credit">Credit</option>
        <option  value="payment">Payment</option>
        <option  value="return">Return</option>

    </select>
</form>

function sale_credit(id) {
  var cust_name = $('#cust_name').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajx_typ1.php',
    data: 'id=' + id,
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#sale_type1").html(msg);

    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajx_typ3.php',
    data: 'id=' + id,
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#sale_type3").html(msg);

    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajx_typ2.php',
    data: 'id=' + id,
    success: function(msg) {
      $("#sale_type2").html(msg);

    }
  });


}
```

ajx_check_sale.php

```
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/variables.php");
 require_once("codelibrary/inc/functions.php");
 echo $cust_name=$_POST['cust_name'];
 echo $return=$_POST['total'];

 $cus="select sum(total) as total_sum from customer where id='$cust_id'";
 $cus2=mysql_query($cus);
 $fet=mysql_fetch_array($cus2);
 $total=$fet['total_sum'];

if($return>$total)
 {
     $status=0; 
     echo $status;  
 }
else
 {
      $status=1;    
      echo $status;     
 }
```

Comment: "It's not worikng" is not a good question. Please elaborate with the errors you have in console and network tab

Comment: Can you ay the reason plzz..

Comment: In your code `sale_type` value comes from a selectbox or textfield?

Comment: plz look my code,edited,select box is used

Comment: console---Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function add_sale.php:200
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'old_password' of undefined add_sale.php:373
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib/angular-route.min.js.map
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib/jquery.min.map
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib/angular.min.js.map

Comment: network--angular-route.min.js.map
ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib
GET
(failed)
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Other
0 B
0 B
1 ms
-
jquery.min.map
ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib
GET
(failed)
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Other
0 B
0 B
1 ms
-
angular.min.js.map
ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib
GET
(failed)
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Other
0 B
0 B
1 ms
-

Comment: What does you `function sale_credit()` do? show us the code.

Comment: added the code sale_credit(),,i got the sale_type value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are syntax error but maybe you can check it after running the website then right click on the web site and select Inspect Elements then go to Console. You might find something there. You can also use console.log('message'); . It will function like alert but would display only at the Console Tab.

Comment: console---Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'old_password' of undefined add_sale.php:376
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib/jquery.min.map
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib/angular.min.js.map
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://ibnjmihbbanannlbobkbmnmckjnmdnom/lib/angular-route.min.js.map